# Computer Graphics: Practical translate to origin method

Tags: java, math, graphics, 3d

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to implement translations on polygons manually, e.g. with plain Java AWT and no OpenGL, in order to understand the concepts better.

I want to perform a "translation to origin" before (and hence after) I do a scaling / rotation on my object, but then comes the question - by which vertex of the polygon do I calculate the distance to the origin?

### Intuition

My intuition is to calculate the distance of each vertex to the origin, and once I find the closest one, calculate the x,y values required to translate it to the origin, and then translate all the polygon's verices with those x,y.

Am I right?

### Another catch

I've implemented a view through camera in my program, such that I've got full viewing pipeline taking polygons in world objects, transforming all coordinates to viewing coordinates, projecting them to 2D and then transforming them to viewport coordinates.

My camera has it's position, lookAt point and up vector, and I want the scaling / rotations to be done **with regard to the lookAt point**.

How can I achieve this? Does it just mean to translate each polygon to the lookAt point instead to the origin?

Comment: Objects usually have their own local coordinate systems. You calculate the translation as the difference of the local and the global coordinate system.

Comment: I do not have local coordinate system here. All polygons are in world coordinates already...

Comment: Then you have to define one. There is no one correct intrinsic local coordinate system. You could use the polygon's centroid as the origin. Or an arbitrary vertex.